# Problema con date() y fecha javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Tengo dos fechas, una fecha que es de hace dos dias que la extraigo de `mongodb, 2021-05-12T23:23:52.456Z` que en microsegundos es `1620861832456` La fecha de hoy con `Date.now() Fri May 14 2021 01:56:15 GMT-0300` que en microsegundos es `1620967674069`

cuando hago la resta `1620967674069 - 1620861832456 = 105841613` <- este valor cuando lo paso a date me deberia dar que son dos dias, pero me da cualquier cosa

una fecha la consigo de una base de datos mongodb, y la otra la genero en javascript con Date.now()

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2):

La medida de tiempo estándar según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#descripci.c3.b3n), se maneja en milisegundos, no en microsegundos.

> La fecha se mide en milisegundos desde la media noche exacta del 01 de enero de 1970 en formato UTC.

Ahora, para resolver tu problema debes de tener en cuenta que un día tiene 86400000 milisegundos (también se menciona en la documentación), o lo que es lo mismo a `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24`. `1000` milisegundos hacen un segundo. `60` segundos hacen un minuto. `60` minutos hacen una hora. `24` horas hacen un día.

Partiendo de esta información, la operación es bastante sencilla, haces la operación de diferencia y divides el resultado -la cantidad de milisegundos- entre 86400000 para convertir los milisegundos a días.

Debes de tomar en cuenta que aunque la diferencia en días (tomando como referencia el valor numérico de los días) es dos, la cantidad de horas transcurridas en ambas fechas afectará el resultado, pues no es lo mismo medir desde las 11 de la noche de hoy a medio día de mañana. La cantidad de días transcurridos según la fecha habrá sido de un día, pero tomando en cuenta las horas, para que realmente sea un día completo la diferencia debe de ser de 24 horas, y solo han transcurrido 13 horas. Claro, esto lo puedes solucionar fácilmente aplicando un redondeo.

```js
const date = new Date('2021-05-12T23:23:52.456Z');
const today = Date.now();

console.log(today, date.getTime());

console.log('Tiempo real: ', (today - date) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
console.log('Tiempo ajustado: ', Math.ceil(Math.abs(today - date) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
console.log('Tiempo ajustado: ', Math.ceil(Math.abs(date - today) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
```

La idea de usar el valor absoluto, es que pudieras cambiar el orden de las fechas para obtener la diferencia y aún así, seguirías obteniendo el mismo resultado.

Luego puedes hacer una función para reutilizar el código.

```javascript
function dateDiffFromNow(date1, date2 = Date.now()) {
  const MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  return Math.ceil(Math.abs(date1 - date2) / MS_PER_DAY);
}

const date = new Date("2021-05-12T23:23:52.456Z");

// Ya no es necesario crear Date.now() puesto que es
// el valor por defecto para date2
console.log(dateDiffFromNow(date));             // La salida para todos
console.log(dateDiffFromNow(date, Date.now())); // los casos será la
console.log(dateDiffFromNow(Date.now(), date)); // misma
```

Si quieres evitar todas estas complicaciones de cálculo, y también las complicaciones que pudieran darte las distintas zonas horarias, puedes usar [`.diff()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) de la librería [moment](https://momentjs.com/).